# EF DatabaseIntializer looping through list methods with overloads,

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Below is my `Intializer.cs` and I was told in order to keep my Guids i had to use Navigation properties so that i had the right relations in my database([Reusing a GUID in EF Code First DatabaseIntializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492367/reusing-a-guid-in-ef-code-first-databaseintializer)). That seems to solves the issues i had earlier but now that i want to take my information and use a Seed to actually add it to the database, i am not sure how to satisfy this error. I get the error for `addUsers(Applications apps)`"eflogin.Models.Applications is a 'type' being used like a variable." I got the feeling i am doing this way wrong.

```
public class DatabaseIntializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
        {
protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
                {
                    addApplications().ForEach(a => context.Applications.Add(a));
                    addUsers(Applications apps).ForEach(u => context.User.Add(u));
                      // if i take out Applications apps
                      // i get No overload for method"addUsers" takes 0 arguments 
                }

private static List<Applications> addApplications()
            {

                var apps = new List<Applications>
                {
                    new Applications
                    {
                      ApplicationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                      ApplicationName = "Test Login"

                    }
                };

                return apps;
            }
private static List<Users> addUsers(Applications apps)
            {
                var use = new List<Users>
                {
                    new Users
                    {
                        UserId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        UserApplication = apps,
                        UserName = "Ralph",
                        IsAnonymouse = false,
                        LastActivityDate = System.DateTime.Now


                    }
                };
                return use;

            }
```

Comment: if you vote it down, leave a reason why +1 for being a valid question to offset the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your are passing in the type and instance in the call to the addUsers method.

```
addUsers(Applications apps)
```

If you remove Applications and just leave apps like so.

```
addUsers(apps)
```

You will get another error because you are passing in a collection of objects and the method expects a single instance.

Here is a suggested edit to your Seed method that should get you past both errors.

```
var apps = addApplications();
apps.ForEach(a => context.Applications.Add(a));

foreach (var app in apps)
{
    var users = addUsers(app)
    users.ForEach(u => context.User.Add(u));
}
```

Note: I think keeping the entity names plural helps in causing some confusion.

Comment: I get it so far can you explain the `var app in apps`. Sorry that is the only thing i don't understand. i know `var app` declares it but how is it in `apps`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are not clear on but here are perhaps some relevant pages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: can you do this with multiple overloads `addUserInRoles(User use, Roles roles).ForEach(ur => context.UserInRoles.Add(ur));`?

Comment: Do you mean overload or do you simply mean multiple parameters because your sample code has no addUserInRoles method?

Comment: Sorry wrong terminology. you are correct multiple parameters.

Comment: Yes, but again you wouldn't use the type in the method call. Instead you write `addUserInRoles(user, role);`.

Comment: Yea i just wanted to make sure i could separate them with commas

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23338/discussion-between-sacrilege-and-jackncoke)